# How to convert gulp watch script into gulp 4

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gulp

I have upgraded my node version to v12 recently and i have an angular project which is running on gulp 3.8, by following some suggestions I have upgraded my gulp version to 4.0 and modified some scripts with gulp.series and parallel. but I'm getting problem in this below script. Can any once help me to convert the below watch file into gulp 4.0 script.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var paths = gulp.paths;

gulp.task('watch', ['inject'], function () {
  gulp.watch([
    paths.src + '/*.html',
    paths.src + '/{app,components}/**/*.less',
    paths.src + '/{app,components}/**/*.js',
    'bower.json'
  ], ['inject']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('inject', function () {
  gulp.watch([
    paths.src + '/*.html',
    paths.src + '/{app,components}/**/*.less',
    paths.src + '/{app,components}/**/*.js',
    'bower.json'

   ], 'inject');  // this should work as well since you have only one task to run
  //   however in the future you may want to add another task as in the below.
  // ], gulp.series('inject', 'anotherTask`));



}));
```

Tasks are not in arrays in v4, but in `gulp.series` or `gulp.parallel`.